# Vertically stacked fixed top html elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the [twitter bootstrap fluid](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/fluid.html) css to build a cms(Dotnetnuke) skin. The cms displays a control panel which is fixed to the top of the page when an admin is logged in.
This is how it looks like

```
<div id="dnnCPWrap"> ... </div>

#dnnCPWrap {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1001 !important;
}
```

The bootstrap fluid's menu looks like this

```
<div class="navbar-fixed-top"> ... </div>

.navbar-fixed-top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

As you can see, they both are fixed to the top of the window and since the fluid menu has a higher z-index, it covers the cms's control panel. Question is, is it possible to have them stack on top of each other with the control panel stacked on top?

**Note:**The cms's control panel is only displayed when an admin is logged in so users don't see it. Thanks

Comment: In your html, wich div is displayed first? ADMIN panel or USER panel?

Comment: The admin's user control panel div is first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with:

#### New css class:

```
.navbar-admin-mode {top: 36px;z-index:1000;}
```

#### Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cp = $("#dnnCPWrap")[0];
    if (typeof cp !== "undefined") {
      $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("navbar-admin-mode");
    }
});
```

Since the admin control panel div(#dnnCPWrap) only exists if the user is logged in as admin, the css class is only added to the skin's menu only for admins.

Answer (score 0):

I think the quick solution is to edit here the css:

```
#dnnCPWrap {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;       
  top: 0px;       /*PUT THE HEIGHT OF THE USER NAV MENU */
  z-index: 1001 !important;
}
```

With that solution the admin panel is displayed below the nav menu of the user.

If you want to have the admin menu first, I think that you have to overwrite the css of the user menu when you log as admin and edit `top:/*HEIGHT OF ADMIN MENU*/`

Comment: while this would move the admin's control panel down, it would alter default behavior of the cms which my client would not like.

Comment: But a simple client see the admin menu?

Comment: Yes clients administer their own sites, so they would see the panel has moved from where it normally is

Comment: Alter the other class top value!

Comment: If you notice, I mentioned that the admin control panel is displayed only when an admin is logged in. Your solution would push the menu down permanently even for regular users. Thanks for your efforts though.

Comment: Build a function in PHP that echo the admin menu only when the admin si logged in.

Comment: The server code(C#) is already doing this. See my own answer for the solution I came up with. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, can't comment yet. For Dnn 7.2.x the selector should use #ControlBar_ControlPanel instead of #dnnCPWrap to make it work.